# Time query erreur _ talend

Tags: talend, query-timeout

Could you please help me find solution for this error?
Thanks a lot

> Exception in component tDBInput_2 (v7)
> org.talend.components.api.exception.ComponentException:
> UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION:{message=Error executing query. Total time 900.205 seconds.
>
> QUERY [VIRTUAL] [QUERY_TIMEOUT]
> }
> at org.talend.components.jdbc.CommonUtils.newComponentException(CommonUtils.java:567)
> at org.talend.components.jdbc.runtime.reader.JDBCInputReader.advance(JDBCInputReader.java:235)
> at org.talend.codegen.flowvariables.runtime.FlowVariablesReader.advance(FlowVariablesReader.java:78)
> at elmira.v7_0_1.v7.tDBInput_2Process(v7.java:1186)
> at elmira.v7_0_1.v7.runJobInTOS(v7.java:2087)
> at elmira.v7_0_1.v7.main(v7.java:1938)
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error executing query. Total time 900.205 seconds.
>
> QUERY [VIRTUAL] [QUERY_TIMEOUT]
>
> at com.denodo.vdb.jdbcdriver.dao.DAOVDBProxy.generateSQLException(DAOVDBProxy.java:485)
> at com.denodo.vdb.jdbcdriver.VDBJDBCAsyncResultSet.next(VDBJDBCAsyncResultSet.java:1801)
> at org.talend.components.jdbc.runtime.reader.JDBCInputReader.haveNext(JDBCInputReader.java:220)
> at org.talend.components.jdbc.runtime.reader.JDBCInputReader.advance(JDBCInputReader.java:233)
> ... 4 more
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: QUERY [VIRTUAL] [QUERY_TIMEOUT]
> at com.denodo.vdb.jdbcdriver.dao.DAOVDBProxy.generateSQLException(DAOVDBProxy.java:485)
> at com.denodo.vdb.jdbcdriver.dao.DAOVDBProxy.generateSQLException(DAOVDBProxy.java:484)

I have just 5 columns and I have deleted all the unnecessary columns

Comment: Are you able to run the query in an SQL Client like dBeaver?

Comment: Try adding your query here, and some sample data and expected output. Also what version of Talend, and what database and version are you using (some of the components are more buggy than others)?